# How to create dynamic checkbox on JSON response in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, checkbox

I am a new bee in react native. Forgive me if I am asking repeated question. I am asking the relative question because the questions asked before on this topic is not helpful for me.
I want to create the dynamic checkbox on the basis of JSON response, I have collected the data in an array, below is the code.

```
sellablePartsCategory = [];
```

the sellablePartsCategory contains the data

```
sellablePartsCategory = ["Brake", "Suspension", "Engine", "Tyre"]

renderParts(){
    for(let i=0; i<sellablePartsCategory.length; i++){
      return(
        <CheckBoxComponent 
            title={sellablePartsCategory[i]}
            checked= {true} /> );
    }
}

 render(){
 <View>
    <Text> {sellablePartsCategory} </Text>
      {this.renderParts()}
 </View> }
```

I know that return statement is breaking the for loop and make it run only one time. It is giving me the zero index value of array and then loop gets break. I don't know how to solve issue.
The CheckBoxComponent.js is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';                         
import {TextInput, StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';   
import { CheckBox, ListItem, List } from 'react-native-elements';  
const CheckBoxComponent = ({title, checked}) => {
return (
    <CheckBox
        title={title}
        checkedColor='#0D4A8E'
        checked={checked}
        />
);};

export { CheckBoxComponent };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `renderParts()` method, you can return all the checkboxes inside a list, using only a single return. Try the code below:

```
renderParts(){
    let checkBoxComponentList = [];
    for(let i=0; i<sellablePartsCategory.length; i++){
        checkBoxComponentList.push(<CheckBoxComponent 
            title={sellablePartsCategory[i]}
            checked= {true} />);
    }
    return checkBoxComponentList;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `key` prop for `CheckBoxComponent`. Also you can use `sellablePartsCategory.map(callbackFunction)` to optimize this code a little)

Comment: Happy to help :) also, merged your edit to answer @fazeelreact :)

Comment: @KartalErkoc How can I handle onPress event for each check box that to be checked?

Comment: @fazeelreact , well that requires another question and answer thread, but just to give you an idea, you can keep your `checked` value as a `state` in your `CheckBoxComponent` and toggle it between true and false when pressed. This also requires you to add `onPress` prop function to your `CheckBox` elements just like `checkedColor` and `checked` props. You may ask that as a separate question maybe. Because, I cannot change the answer above as it addresses a correct answer to your initial question.

Comment: hi @fazeelreact , can you mark the answer as accepted? That will be helpful for me as well :)